# Finding unit normal vector in case of flux across a curve

Tags: integration, gradient-flows, greens-theorem

I was 'lucky' to blunder through previous exams concerning finding a normal unit vector given a tangent vector.

Finding the tangent vector and the unit tangent vector is easy. 
But how does one determines the correct unit normal vector? My text says that the unit normal vector is found by rotating the unit tangent vector through an angle of pi/2. What does this mean? Is this a transformation or mapping? I highly doubt so.

Comment: In how many variables? In two variables you only have a direction of rotation but in three (or more) dimensional space it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Case is in 2 variables.

Comment: Then, yes, the normal vector has an angle of $\pi/2$ with the tangent, so that they are orthogonal. In practice, if the tangent vector is $(a,b)$ you can simply take $(-b,a)$, which ensures orthogonality. (Use the dot product)

Comment: And what happens if we are interested instead in the unit normal vector pointing inwards? What changes?

Comment: If you want the vector in the other direction, just change sign.